# SQL Query parser for Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql-parser, jsqlparser

I am looking for SQL query parser for MySQL queries. Using which I can parse the query, modify the query object and print back modified query

JSQL Parser was exactly what I needed but It has 2 main issues while escaping single quote inside column values
https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/issues/167
https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/issues/166

So I am looking for open source alternative which can help me with the task

Presto-parser I tried was not able to parse Update queries

If anyone else is aware of any other reliable SQL Parsing library please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Regarding **JSqlParser**:

**Issue 166** already fixed.

The escaping of single quotes is not supported, but using double single quotes is. Therefore someone could replace all **\'** using **''** before parsing.

**EDIT:** **Issue 167** fixed within actual Snapshot 0.9.5 of JSqlParser.

Answer (score 1):

One year ago i search for the same thing but finally i use another approach. Those were the projects that i found to parse sql.

- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr3.org/). Is commonly used generic parser. It's a kind of parser generator. From a set of rules it writes the java code. There are rules for a lot of thins like spanish, java or sql.
- [JParsec](https://github.com/abailly/jparsec). Seems similar to the previous one. Seems that already exists SQL rules, but does not seem easy to use.
- [ZQL](http://zql.sourceforge.net/). Uses JavaCC to auto-generate Java code that parses the SQL. I test this one but i can not get it working as i want. And i think that the project is discontinued.
- [sql-parser](https://github.com/FoundationDB/sql-parser). It looks nice, but when i tested it i can not get it working. The link seems to not work, but i think that [this is a fork](https://github.com/lchaboud-restlet/fdb-sqlparser) of the original project.
- [jOOQ](https://github.com/lchaboud-restlet/fdb-sqlparser) is a great library for those that don't need or like an ORM and also has a parser.

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder I add it. But take into account that this post was written in 2015, and I don't review the topic since then.